# Drupal commerce multicurrency

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

So I'm trying to change to currency on my local drupal site (with room module) from USD to INR. The unit price gets converted just fine but when is comes to the order total, it's just wrong. For instance:

I booked a single room that costs 1000 INR
I booked a double room that costs 1200 INR
But when it comes to the order total, it sums up to be something like 141200 INR instead of 2200 INR. I can't seem to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided no information about how you are handling your converting but the problem is pretty clear.

You are converting the price twice, thats the issue. Somehow in the current situation  the system thinks the 2200 total price is in USD, and calculates it to IND.

Comment: I resolved the issue, thank you. That's what was happening. I just uninstalled the module and redid it and weirdly, it seemed to work just fine this time.